# Debug target is missing - how to set in VS 2010 Express?

Tags: arcobjects, add-in, visual-studio, arcgis-10.2

I updated ArcGIS from 10.1 to 10.2 and recompiled all Addins with ArcObjects 10.2.  I am having an issue with 1 addin that accesses a custom tool in a toolbox and want to debug the project.  However, when i hit run I get a "...the debug target '' is missing" erro message.  The path is still set to the Desktop10.1 target - **HOW DO I RESET IT to Desktop10.2 in VS 2010 EXPRESS.** I only found instruction on how this can be dine in the full version if VS but this option is not avaialble in the express version.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Found it. 
Open **ProjectName.vbproj.user** (Where ProjectName is the actual name of the project) in notepad and change **Desktop10.1** to **Desktop 10.2**:

Program
  C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\bin\ArcMap.exe